# How do I run tail on a pcap file remotely?

Tags: wireshark, remote-server, pcap, tail

I have a pcap file that is growing over time on a server that I can ssh into. What I want to do is something like this:

```
ssh x@y tail -f -c +0 /path/to/pcapfile | wireshark -k -i
```

This command returns an error stating that the pcap file I specified cannot be found (it exists).

I have also tried

```
wireshark -k -i - < (ssh x@y "tail -f -c +0 /path/to/pcapfile")
```

None of these work. What I want to do is use the tail command remotely to display the packets that are streaming live from the growing pcap file in the server. How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `-t`? Like this `ssh -t x@y tail -f -c +0 /path/to/pcapfile | wireshark -k -i`

Comment: Yeah I tried it, it says unrecognized libpcap format. I also checked the versions of wireshark on both my machine and the server, both are the same.

Comment: Is the `tail` command on your system guaranteed to work on binary files?  pcap files aren't text files.

Comment: it works when I run it locally, so I know it works with pcap files. the problem is when I run it remotely

Comment: In the first command you tried, you forgot the minus at the end to tell wireshark to read from stdin: `wireshark -k -i -`

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `tail` does not know where a packet starts and where it ends.  The fact that it works locally is likely just a coincidence: packets come at a rate that is slow enough for `tail` to send them individually to `wireshark` through the pipe.

On the other hand, this is not a problem that other people have not had before.  [Anton Berzin](https://github.com/tobez) wrote [`pcaptail`](http://blog.tobez.org/posts/pcaptail/), which is the tool you're likely looking for:

> It (pcaptail) will behave like tail -f but on the level of individual packets

`pcaptail` is a very small program: less than 300 lines of code, and you only need `libpcap` and `libpcap` headers to compile it.